Calculate the contour integral of $\oint_C (xy + i 2x^2)dz$
Calculate the contour integral of $\oint_C (xy + i 2x^2)dz$ where $C$ consists of the contour $\sigma(t) = t^2 + it^3$, $ 0 \leq t \leq 1$, followed by the line segment from $1 + i$ to $0$.
I am using the parametrization $\oint_C f(z)dz =\oint_{\sigma(t)}f(\sigma(t))\sigma'(t)dt$
For the first part, I try $\sigma(t) = x(t) + iy(t)$, $x(t) = t^2$ & $y(t) = t^3$ meaning the integral can be parametrized as
$\int_{0}^{1} (t^2t^3 + i 2t^4)(2t + i3t^2) dt $
$ = \int_{0}^{1} (-4t^6) dt \ + i \int_{0}^{1} (3t^7 + 4t^5) dt $
$ = \frac{-4}{7} + i\frac{25}{24}$
for the second part, I let the line segment be parametrised by $\sigma(t) = (1 - t)(1+i)$
which gives a contour integral of
$(1 - 3i)\int_{0}^{1} (1 - t)^2dt \ = \frac{1}{3} - i$
I expected the sum of these two integrals to be zero so I am wondering what I am doing wrong.

Usually the integral is zero if the function is holomorphic, if it is not it may not, check that this function does not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations, hence it is not holomorphic

@number8 I'm not sure why you think it's holomorphic, but it is not.

Each of your answers for the two integrals is correct (for instance, as verified by the Mathematica code Map[reg |-> ContourIntegrate[x  y + I  2  x^2 /. {x -> Re[z], y -> Im[z]}, z∈reg ], {ParametricRegion[{t^2, t^3}, {{t, 0, 1}}], Line[{{1, 1}, {0, 0}}]}]).
As mentioned in the comments, while the integral of a function that is holomorphic (or that has an antiderivative throughout the region enclosed by the contour) would be zero, the function you have here does not satisfy either of those conditions. For instance, it is not holomorphic because it fails any Cauchy-Riemann Equation.
